# 14.10/14.04LTS New installation won't boot?

Tags: 14.04, boot, system-installation, 14.10, bios

I have a Lenovo Thinkpad Yoga (S1), and I install through a flash drive. After the notice pop up and say installed successfully and restart. The laptop will boot up and stop at boot device choice screen and do nothing. When I try to entry the only drive I had. It just flash and take me right back that screen. Secure boot is off and boot mode set to UEFI-CSM ON. I have try the two newest version available. None of them work.
What could be the problem?

Comment: Is your setup dual boot with Windows?  If so,you cannot have CSM turned on.  Did you turn off fast boot in the Windows power settings?

Comment: @ubfan1 I did not setting up dual os and I did not turn off fast boot on windows before i uninstall it. Do I need to install it back, turn it off and uninstall it again? Thx.

Comment: No, you shouldn't need to install/uninstall Windows, the fast boot is meaningless without Windows installed.  I guess you should run boot-repair and post the information link so we can see what's happening.

Comment: @ubfan1 If I need to run boot repair, Ubuntu need at least start booting？ My Laptop won't even make it to that step. I have also try to lock boot mode to legacy, it did not work either.

Comment: The forums might be a better place to fix you up: http://ubuntuforums.org/forumdisplay.php?f=333
The Ubuntu install media should boot either in UEFI or CSM mode.

Comment: The Ubuntu boot-repair options can be found on the **[Official Ubuntu help pages](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)** when you've run them, report the link back here...